# Error when creating database record on rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, models

I'm trying to create a new record through the rails console but I'm getting the following error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  database "my_database_development" does not exist
```

I've recently changed from Sqlite3 to PG to be able to deploy to Heroku. Is this what is giving the error?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have not yet run

```
rake db:create
```

This will "create" the databases on your PostgreSQL server.  A step that you didn't have to do with SQLite, but Postgres requires it.  As TK-421 said, make sure that your database.yml is configured for your OS and Postgres, not SQLite.

Here is a (possibly outdated) Railscast on the topic.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

Is this running locally, or on Heroku? In `config/database.yml`, the local user you specify will need to have `CREATEDB` privileges (as a superuser, for example).

There's a little more configuration required in this case than for SQLite. Google will show you a bunch of tutorials specific to your OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you see this problem in production on heroku, start the console like this:

```
rails console production
```

If you have that problem in development on your machine, check your `config/database.yml`. It is points to a local development database that does not exist.